# Return value that is within a then async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I do not know how to return the value of the variable values ​​found in the first function and then use them as shown below with the then ().

```
 async escribeSolido(contenido: any) {
        const ancho = 300;
        ...
        contenido.map(async (item: any) => {

            let image = new Jimp(ancho, alto, item.color, (err: any, imagen: any) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            });
            Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK)
            .then(font => {
                ...
                return image;
            })
            .then(async(image) => {

                let file =  uuid()+'.png';
                const path =  __dirname +'/public/'+file;
                values = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(path, {folder: 'anuncios_basicos'});
                /*Return this values*/
                console.log('Values -----: ', values);           
            })          
            })
        });
        //return values;
    }
```

My other function

```
await abService.escribeSolido(contenido)
                    .then((value: any) => console.log('Values: ', value)) // undefined
                    .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
```

My results

```
Values:  undefined
POST /api/anuncio 200 75.451 ms - 463
Values -----:  { public_id: 'anuncios_basicos/qnp6s1ptxwzxc0rrwzhp',
  ....
  url:
   'http://res.cloudinary.com/dshskwox0/image/upload/v1554922819/anuncios_basicos/qnp6s1ptxwzxc0rrwzhp.png',
  secure_url:
   'https://res.cloudinary.com/dshskwox0/image/upload/v1554922819/anuncios_basicos/qnp6s1ptxwzxc0rrwzhp.png',
  original_filename: 'e59df336-eba1-4b17-9101-fe6bfeed07dc' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the values where your console.log statement is. This will return values to your array that is constructed from the array. To return the array of values from your escribeSolido function, simply put return infront of your map.